# Multiple return statements from single lamda function in lex

Tags: azure, aws-lambda, aws-lex

I am trying to migrate a bot from microsoft azure to aws lex.
In azure we can use multiple session.send() statements to send multiple responses to a single user input.
But in aws lex we can not use multiple return statements in lambda function.

In my azure bot I am sending a response after every 5 minute to the user.
e.g:-

```js
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 300000);

function myTimer() {
    session.send(message);
}
```

How to achieve this in aws lex using lambda function.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to trigger a second response from a "post-Lex" Lambda, meaning a Lambda Function that comes after Lex. You would need a "pre-Lex" Lambda Function that passes the user input to Lex and returns Lex responses back to the user.

---

**This is the basic set up of a Lex bot:**
[image]

---

**But this is how you would need it set up:**
[image]

---

It doesn't actually need to be a Lambda Function between the user and Lex but either way, it will need to use [Lex Runtime Service API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/API_Operations_Amazon_Lex_Runtime_Service.html) with [PostContent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/API_runtime_PostContent.html) or [PostText](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/API_runtime_PostText.html) to pass the `userInput` to Lex.

Here's an Amazon blog on how they used Lambda this way, in what they call a "pre-processing layer" between a channel and Lex: [Integrate Your Amazon Lex Bot with Any Messaging Service](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/integrate-your-amazon-lex-bot-with-any-messaging-service/)

You'll see that they also use [AWS API Gateway](https://console.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/home?region=us-east-1#/welcome) to create an HTTPS endpoint in order to connect the user's channel to this "pre-processing" Lambda.

---

After setting up any type of "pre-processing" layer, it is in there that you can get around Lex's limitations on responses and would only have to worry about the channel's limitations.

**Friendly Warning:** I believe Amazon has set up these limitations in Lex to discourage chatbot developers from spamming users, and when you say *"I am sending a response after every 5 minute to the user"*, it definitely sounds like it could become spam. So be careful with that.

Comment: Thanks, but I have a doubt,my azure chatbot is deoloyed on slack so how will that happen using this pre-Lex lambda function. How will the message from slack will go to lambda using aws slack integration as when we deploy a lex bot on slack, input goes to lex only, from lex it goes to lambda.

Comment: Also, this 5 min interval is not spamming, my bot is like a polling bot, so evey 5 min it does a API call inside code and depending upon the results it displays value to user. Not sure how this pre-Lex lambda function will integrate to slack. I want a user input from slack, then it should start polling and display the results after every 5 min.

Comment: You could ask a new question: "How to integrate Slack with Lambda?" But here are a couple links from Slack API: [Creating an AWS Lambda Function and API Endpoint](https://api.slack.com/tutorials/aws-lambda) and [Handling events from the Events API using AWS Lambda](https://api.slack.com/tutorials/events-api-using-aws-lambda) P.S. Thanks for explaining it being non-spam, I'll leave the Friendly Warning for others.